# Combining UPDATE with WINDOW in pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to achieve the following:

Starting from the table below

```
id  town  x    y
1   A     1.0  1.0
2   A     2.0  3.5
3   A     4.0  2.0
4   B     6.0  8.0
5   B     7.5  8.5
```

I want to have it updated with two new columns containing the averages of x and y for both towns A and B like below

```
id  town  x    y    avg_x  avg_y
1   A     1.0  1.0  2.3333 2.1666
2   A     2.0  3.5  2.3333 2.1666
3   A     4.0  2.0  2.3333 2.1666
4   B     6.0  8.0  6.75   8.25
5   B     7.5  8.5  6.75   8.25
```

I created the two new columns with an ALTER statement and then tried the following:

```
UPDATE table
SET (avg_x, avg_y) =
(SELECT AVG(x) OVER w, AVG(y) OVER w
FROM table
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY town));
```

which returns me:
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000

I am stuck and would greatly appreciate help.

Comment: Don't add averages into the table.. calculate them in a query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use aggregation:

```
update t
    set avg_x = tt.avg_x,
        avg_y = tt.avg_y
    from (select town, avg(x) as avg_x, avg(y) as avg_y
          from t
          group by town
         ) tt
    where t.town = tt.town;
```

Or don't bother and just calculate the value on the fly when you need it.